# Ajax post to webapi core is always null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have a problem with ajax call to webapi and posting complex javascript object to server.
If I post the object without children array everything works fine. When I post with children object the posted data is null.

This is the example of the working object

```
{"IdNews": 0, "DataNews": "2018-01-01T12:00", "Visualizza": true, "DataPubblicazione": "2018-01-01T12:00"}
```

this is the NON working object

```
{ "IdNews": 0, "DataNews": "2018-01-01T12:00", "Visualizza": true, "DataPubblicazione": "2018-01-01T12:00","NewsLingues": [{"IdLingua": 1,"Titolo": "dsfgf","Testo": "dfghdfghdfg"}]}
```

I checked the object properties and the are correct.

This is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myapi',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

and the webappi code is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("set")]
public dynamic Set([FromBody]News obj)
{
    //TODO
    return (item);
}
```

obj is always null.
I tried various solution, changed the contentType to 'application/json', removed contentType but none is working.

Here the structure of News object (created with LLBLGen using EF Core 2.0)

```
public partial class News : CommonEntityBase
{
    #region Class Extensibility Methods
    /// <summary>Method called from the constructor</summary>
    partial void OnCreated();
    #endregion
    private System.Int32 _idNews = default(System.Int32);

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="News"/> class.</summary>
    public News() : base()
    {
        this.NewsLingues = new List<NewsLingue>();
        this.Slugs = new List<Slug>();
        OnCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the DataInserimento field. </summary>
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataInserimento { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the DataNews field. </summary>
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataNews { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the DataPubblicazione field. </summary>
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataPubblicazione { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Gets the IdNews field. </summary>
    public System.Int32 IdNews => _idNews;
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the IdTenant field. </summary>
    public Nullable<System.Int32> IdTenant { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the Visualizza field. </summary>
    public Nullable<System.Boolean> Visualizza { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Represents the navigator which is mapped onto the association 'NewsLingue.News - News.NewsLingues (m:1)'</summary>
    public List<NewsLingue> NewsLingues { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Represents the navigator which is mapped onto the association 'Slug.News - News.Slugs (m:1)'</summary>
    public List<Slug> Slugs { get; set;}
    /// <summary>Represents the navigator which is mapped onto the association 'News.Tenant - Tenant.News (m:1)'</summary>
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Show the News properties also

Comment: Have you tried the ajax call without calling JSON.stringify on the data? Just do data: data

Comment: Your code looks fine. You should check the type of `NewsLingues `. It should be `public IEnumerable<NewsLingue> NewsLingues { get; set; }`.

Comment: As request of sir_ask I added the structure of the object. I tried to remove the JSON.stringify and I tried to make an IEnumerable in stead of List, but none of this is working.